# NextJs useEffect triggers every time I route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am building a nextjs blog app.

In the current blog layout, I managed to fetch data on my sidebar (I need it to show my "recent posts" there) using the useEffect/fetch (because getInitialProps works only under Pages) but it triggers whenever I route between pages. (it goes blank for a sec and reloads the post titles)

Is there a way to disable this behaviour after the initial load and create a constant or smth? I used the "[]" method but still no luck:

```js
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('/api/posts');
      const {data} = await res.json();
      setPosts(data)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, []);
```

Or is there a better way to fetch data on my sidebar? This is the only solution I managed to make it work but it is half-working.

Comment: A useEffect will run every time a component remounts. Which is fine, except that you are unconditionally fetching in the callback you give it. You just need to do `if (!dataAlreadyHere) fetchData();`

Comment: i think we need more info here: what does the component look like where this useEffect is being used? Where does the component live? inside a page? inside another component? How are you routing between pages (server or client navigation)? there are too many unknown variables

Comment: Another interesting point is, when I put a console.log(posts) right before the return, I get an empty array on my console when I refresh the page. But somehow I am fetching the data because I see the titles on my app.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


export default function RightBar() {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('/api/posts');
      const {data} = await res.json();
      setPosts(data)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, []);


    return (
      <div className="rightbar content">
        <div className="rightbarContent">
          <h3 className="sidebarborder"><span className="sidebarheader">Recent Posts</span></h3>
          {posts.slice(0,5).map(posts => {
              return (
                <div key={posts._id}>
                    * <Link href={`/${posts._id}`}>{posts.title}</Link>
                </div>
              )
          })}
          <h3>Categories</h3>
          <p>blabla</p>
        </div>      
      </div>
    )
  }
```

The component layout is this:

Layout > Header Topnav Main Footer

Main has 2 children > LeftBar (where my main content resides) and RightBar (where I show my recent posts)

Layout wraps the index.js page. So I pass props.children to layout > main > leftbar components.

I hope that's explanatory well enough.

Comment: Where did you import the RightBar component ?

Comment: Inside the main component as I explaine above.